# Does an environment NOT on the search path have a parent?

Tags: r

I'm reading through [Hadley Wickham's Advanced R book](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html) and am currently reading the "Environments" chapter

It says that every environment except the emptyenv has a parent. I need help understanding something that clears this up to me - maybe I'm just overcomplicating it or misunderstanding how variables work in R.

Let's say I define my own environment:
`myenv <- new.env()`
Now if I do a simple `parent.env(myenv)` I do get the global env as expected.

But now what happens when I attach this environment, causing it to go in the search path above the global env?
`attach(myenv)`
Now if I look at the search path using `search()` I can see that `myenv` is a parent of `.GlobalEnv`. I can also verify this using `parent.env(globalenv())` which returns `myenv`.  And if I run `parent.env(parent.env(globalenv()))` then I get `tools:rstudio` which makes sense.
**BUT** if I try to look at the parent of `myenv` directly using `parent.env(myenv)` I get the global env. In order to get the result I expect (`tools:rstudio`) I need to cast my environment to an environment manually: `parent.env(as.environment("myenv"))` returns `tools:rstudio`.

So which is correct?  What is the parent environment of myenv?
I know I can change the parent of an environment with `parent.env<-`, but if I just attach it like in the above example, I don't understand what is considered to be the true parent

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that attaching `myenv` creates a **copy** of `myenv` (and also modifies its parent) so we now have two `myenv` environments and they can be and are different.   You have already shown in the question that they have different parents.  Try this in a fresh session to further show that they are distinct:

```
myenv <- new.env()
myenv$x <- 1

# with the attach below we now have 2 myenv environments - 
#   the one above and the new one created in the attach below on the search path.
attach(myenv)

# this changes x in the original myenv but not the x in the copy on the search path
myenv$x <- 2  
myenv$x
## 2

# the copy of myenv on the search path still has the original value of x
as.environment("myenv")$x
## 1
```

Check out this [blog post](http://obeautifulcode.com/R/How-R-Searches-And-Finds-Stuff/) for more.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, and that's a great blog post you linked

Answer (score 6):

The parent environment is the enclosure from which you defined the new environment.  However, this is not so for functions. If you're defining a function, the parent frame will be environment from which it's called, not defined (see `help(sys.parent)`).

The *Environment* documentation is quite informative.

> `new.env` returns a new (empty) environment with (by default) enclosure the parent frame.
>
> `parent.env` returns the enclosing environment of its argument.

So it's no surprise that the parent environment is the global environment.  Had you assigned `myenv` in a different enclosure, that would be its parent.

The empty env is the end of the line

```
parent.env(baseenv())
# <environment: R_EmptyEnv>

parent.env(parent.env(baseenv()))
# Error in parent.env(parent.env(baseenv())) : 
#  the empty environment has no parent
```

And here's something else that's useful...

> If one follows the chain of enclosures found by repeatedly calling `parent.env` from any environment, eventually one reaches the empty environment `emptyenv()`, into which nothing may be assigned.

I guess it also depends on what's on the search path and whether or not you even attach the it to the search path.

```
myenv <- new.env()
attach(myenv)
sapply(search(), function(x) {
    attr(parent.env(as.environment(x)), "name")
})
```

Which gives a list of environments and their parents on the search my path.

```
$.GlobalEnv
[1] "myenv"

$myenv
[1] "package:stringi"

...
...

$`package:base`
NULL

[[12]]
<environment: R_EmptyEnv>
```